# select a h1 element under two specific div class names

Tags: css

```
<div class="top1">
  <div class="top2">
    <h1 class="highlighted">
```

How to select the h1 class in above piece of html code with CSS? The situation is there are duplicate h1 with class "highlighted". Here I just want to select the one under the class top1/top2/highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
.top1 .top2 h1.highlighted{color:red;}
```

`.top1 .top2` means elements having class `top2` where parent is element having class `top1`.

`.top2 h1.highlighted` means `h1` elements having class `highlighted` where parent has class `top2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.top2 {
background: red;
color: white;
}
```

rather than applying css on `<h1>,` make it on its container `<div>`

Comment: We don't know if `.top2` is just a wrapper for the h1 or contains more elements and so on. It may be just fine for him styling the h1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.top1 .top2 h1[class='highlighted']{
       /* style for h1 under top1/top2 */
}
```

OR

```
.top1 .top2 h1.highlighted{
       /* style for h1 under top1/top2 */
}
```

Both shows the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.top1 .top2 h1.highlighted
  color:red;
}
```